# Two numbers "echo" the same but != is true?

Tags: php

I have to compare two numbers.. In some cases even if they are equal an if-statement returns false!?

```
$next_accum = $curr_amount + $csv_arr[$i]['amount'];
var_dump($next_accum);
echo ' ';
var_dump($csv_arr[$i]['accum_amount']);
if($next_accum != $csv_arr[$i]['accum_amount']) echo ' _err';
echo '<br>';
```

I don't get it.. The above prints:

```
int(892474) int(892474)
int(866374) int(866374)
int(741374) int(741374)
int(685124) int(685124)
int(570749) int(570749)
int(520749) int(520749)
int(510819) int(510818) _err
int(474062) int(474063) _err
int(461678) int(461678)
```

Comment: you can round them, cast to integer, use intval() or concat them to become strings. floating point can cause problems when it comes to accuracy, because of how it's representing the memory

Comment: Welcome to the imprecise world of floating-point math!

Comment: if you can not convert it to int, you can check the accuracy like this: if (abs($float1 - $float2) > 0.001) echo 'error;

Comment: have edited my question.. it still returns false even if both are int

Comment: aarh.. now they arent equal :P

Comment: this now gives me another problem.. why is a float ronded up!? argh!!

Comment: @galchen... ok.. it works if the value is converted to a string.. make a question

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if(((int)$next_accum) != ((int)$csv_arr[$i]['accum_amount'])) echo ' error';
```

Comment: I think you mean `(int)` rather than `int()` and the extra parens are unnecessary, you can just do `if ((int) $next_accum != (int) $csv_arr[$i]['accum_amount'])`...

Comment: oops. fixed. tx. was going to suggest intval(), but (int) should work in this case and is a little faster. parens are just for clarity and, yes, optional.

Comment: it don't work if the vars are converted to ints.. then some values is rounded in an odd way.. you need to convert the values to strings

Comment: ok. [convert them to strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) it wasn't clear that you intended the values to be floats since you can't use regular comparison for floats in PHP.